# Sending JSON data from Express to Backbone

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, backbone.js, express

I made a simple Backbone app and I'm trying to use JSON data from a MYSQL database with an Express server. 
When I send a GET request with Express to send data to Backbone, the html template from backbone disapear, there's only the JSON array on the screen. How can I get the data in my html/underscore template ?

**server.js (Express)**

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: '***',
    password: '***',
    database: '***'
});

connection.connect();

app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        res.json(result);
    });
});

app.get('/users/:id', function(req, res) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =' + connection.escape(req.params.id), function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        res.json(result);
    });
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.listen(8080);
```

**app.js (Backbone)**

```js
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    default: {
        id: 0,
        name: 'UserName',
        age: 0
    }
})

var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: User,
    url: '/users'
})

var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#UserViewTemplate').html()),
    tagName: 'li',
    render: function() {
        this.el.innerHTML = this.template(this.model.toJSON())
        return this;
    }
});

var UsersView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#UsersViewTemplate').html()),
    tagName: 'ul',
    render: function() {
        this.el.innerHTML = this.template(this.collection);
        this.collection.each(function(user) {
                var userView = new UserView({
                    model: user
                });
                this.$el.append(userView.render().el);
            }, this) 
        return this;
    }
});

var UserRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'users': 'list'
    },
    list: function() {
        console.log('list function called')
        var usersView = new UsersView({
            collection: users
        })
        $('body').append(usersView.render().el);
    }
})

var users = new Users();

users.fetch().then(function() {
    var router = new UserRouter();
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it ! I just had to use the route **localhost:3000/#users**, not localhost:3000/users.